# Proving $10240...02401$ composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic

I got this question recently, and have been unable to solve it.

> Prove that $1024\underbrace{00 \ldots\ldots 00}_{2014 \text{ times}}2401$ is composite.

I have two different ways in mind.

First is $7^4+400(2^2\cdot10^{504})^4$, which looks like Sophie Germain, but I'm not sure what to do with the $400$. Another thought is that this is almost a palindrome, with the order of just two digits interchanged. I'm not sure where to go from there, and if it'd provide any results, but it seems interesting nonetheless.

Please help.

Comment: What does "102400...(2014 times)...002401" mean? It's not clear to me what should be the $...$.

Comment: It means that $1024$ and $2401$ have $2014\text{ '0'}s$ between them.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your number has $2022$ digits of which $2016$ are zero?

Comment: ok I see. Well I would consider writing that:
$$ 1024\underbrace{00 \ldots\ldots 0}_{2014 \text{ times}}2401$$

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, you are.

Comment: Is it certain that the number *is* composite?

Comment: If I'm correct, First 15000 primes don't divide the given number.

Comment: @Servaes The strong Fermat test to base $2$ says it's composite.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by the strong Fermat test to base $2$?

Comment: @Servaes Write $n-1 = 2^k\cdot m$ with $m$ odd, and then $$a^{n-1} - 1 = (a^m - 1)\prod_{\kappa = 0}^{k-1}\bigl(a^{2^{\kappa} m} + 1\bigr)$$ where $1 < a < n-1$. Then $n$ is a strong Fermat probable prime if $n$ divides one of the factors of the product, i.e. $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ or there is a $\kappa \in \{0,\dotsc, k-1\}$ such that $a^{2^{\kappa}m} \equiv -1\pmod{n}$. That's the test Miller-Rabin is composed of. In this case, $a = 2$ shows it's composite. (Actually already the ordinary Fermat test shows that here.)

Comment: @Daniel: in fact, it is already complete proof of compositeness (even if we cannot provide its factors yet).

Comment: Yes, @Oleg567, but I think a different proof that is more manageable without a computer was intended.

Comment: I found an almost identical question, but with the key difference that the number in question 102400...002401 has 2014 zeros in total, so including the two in 1024 and 2401. That number yields to the Sophie Germain identity. Is it possible that the problem posed to you was a misquoted version of this one? Either way, I'd love to see a solution to this (version of the) problem.

Comment: @TeddantheTerran I don't believe so. This test was an important one, I don't believe the setters would make such an elementary mistake as that.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Where is this from?

Comment: @davidlowryduda RMO practice test by Allen.

Comment: Have you shown us exactly how this question was presented in the practice test? The first way you wrote it was ambiguous, and the other ways were suggested in a comment. Is it possible that the question was presented correctly in the practice test but the same question is not accurately presented here?

Comment: @DavidK Actually, the original way I wrote it was the wrong one. The question had an underbrace, which I did not know the MathJax code for, so I had to make do with the dots thing.

Comment: So, to be clear, in the practice test the original looks (essentially) exactly like the question does now, in which the underbrace is under all of the $0$ digits between the digits $1024$ and $2401$, and there are no other digits over the underbrace. Thanks for clarifying the source.

Comment: Can't be Sophie Germain type argument alone. The polynomial $5^2x^4+7^4$ does take prime values. Even if we restrict $x$ to multiples of $16$. The little bit of testing with Mathematica I did suggests that the number of prime factors is relatively low when the number of consecutive zeros is $\equiv10\pmod{12}$ (which is the case with $2014$ also).

Comment: The smalles prime factor is not in the first ten million primes.

Answer (score 1):

The method introduced in this modification is for reduction of volume of calculations.

Let's start with a simple example; consider number $N=1024002401=1670477\times 613$. We may write:

$N=2^{10}.10^6+24.10^2 +1=2^3.10^2(2^7.10^4+3)+1$

$2^7.10^4+3=1280003 ≡59 \mod (613)$

⇒ $N=2^3.10^2(613 k + 59)+1=800\times 613\times k +800 \times 59 +1$

Let  $800\times 613 =a$ and $800\times 59 +1 =b$

⇒ $(a, b)=613$

Now suppose we do not know that $p=613$ and $r=59$ in following relation:

$(a, b)=(800 p, 800 r+1)=p$

$a=800 r +1$ gives infinite numbers which its factors may be candidates for a factor of a number like ($N=2^{\alpha}.10^{\beta}+3^{\gamma}$).

For example giving r numerous values we find that for $r=59$ we get $800\times 59+1=47201=7\times 11\times 613$. Each of theses three factors can be the candidate for p to be tried to find the factor of N. For $N=2^{10}.10^{2018}+7^4$ we may write:

$N=2^{10}.10^{2018}+7^4=2^3.10^2(2^7.10^{2016}+3)+1$

$2^7.10^{2016}+3≡ r\ mod (p)= k.p +r$

$N=800(k.p+r)+1=800p.k+800r +1$

Now values for $r$ in $(800 r +1)$ give numbers their factors can be checked as a primes factor of N.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It simply puts some weak constraint on the factors of $N$.

Comment: It reduces the number of primes to be checked as the factor of N.